# Impact of dispatchAsync on broker network communication

Tags: activemq-classic

The `dispatchAsync` attribute of the `networkConnector` element is `true` by default. I think it means asyncronous transfer between brokers. Does it mean messages can be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DispatchAsync means the broker is handing the work of tracking acknowledgements off to a worker thread. It does not mean messages will be lost.